# Why aren't revisions before I created my branch greyed out?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, branching-and-merging

I created a branch from trunk in Tortoise SVN and committed some changes to the branch.

I'd like to merge whatever new changes there are from the trunk to the branch before I reintegrate from the branch to the trunk. This will let me resolve any conflicts on the branch. When I bring up the merge dialog in Tortoise, I was expecting all the revisions prior to the point at which I created the branch to be greyed out; instead, none of them were.

Did I miss something when creating the branch (e.g. should I have done a record-only merge at the same time)? Or is it safe to just cherry-pick the new revisions to merge even though Tortoise doesn't know that the earlier revisions are already present?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the `svn:mergeinfo` is not provided in your Branch. You can check this <kbd>Right-Click</kbd>ing your Branch Folder > <kbd>TortoiseSVN</kbd> > <kbd>Properties</kbd>. If is the first branch of your repository, revisions not appearing greyed is a normal fact.

Therefore, use cherrypicking this first time. If all the procedure were made correctly, the next merges will grey the revisions correctly.

Comment: When I did a full merge (without specifying revisions) from the trunk to the branch, it automatically detected which revisions were needed. These now recent changes appear as greyed-out, although the earlier ones do not. I guess that's how it's supposed to work.